# Material Design Lite Programmatically Trigger Floating Label

Tags: javascript, material-design-lite

I am adding a value to an [MDL textfield with floating label](https://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#textfields-section) via JavaScript.  The placeholder remains after the value is added and the floating label does not trigger.

I tried setting focus via JavaScript but it does not work.  I must physically key in a value in order for the label to float.

Does anyone know how to programmatically trigger the floating event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the `MaterialTextfield.change()` method to set the value and trigger the class changes.
But keep in mind, that the **MaterialTextfield** component is the element with  `mdl-js-textfield`
Have a look to this short [hack](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWerBY)

Comment: BTW, I had to use document.querySelector because I am loading the textfield via ajax.